# Code in self host works twice

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, owin, self, self-hosting

In my OWIN self-host app I have controller:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public class AnonController : ApiController
{
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public string Get()
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("DEBUG");
        return "succesful";
    }
}
```

So,after makeing request, in debug window I see following:

```
DEBUG
DEBUG
```

I've tried to debug - it seems code execute once.

I run host as Service, app - WindowsService.
Part of code in WinService.cs

```
using (WebApp.Start<Startup>(url: siteUrl))
{
   Thread.Sleep(Timeout.Infinite);
}
```

Till this moment code executes once.

Comment: Are you sure it's not just a bug of debug output? Because sometimes I also see duplicates in debug window but code executes once.

Comment: Ohhhhh.....It's really was problem with Debug.Log() . After logging in file it was fine. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

How are you making the request?

Not sure if this is related but I have noticed similar behavior in the past when testing **GET** operations from Chrome.

Chrome seems to attempt to "prefetch" a resource at the point it's entered in the address bar and then again when you actually submit the request.